# simple-oauth2 equivalent for C#

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0

In my node.js app I use [simple-oauth2](https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2) to handle oauth tokens. I'm looking for an equivalent in C# to use in Azure. The idea is to store the tokens from `simple-oauth2` to a db and read the in a c# app to use (and refresh) them etc. I'm not able to find any c# libary to read these stored tokens for further use (as client) in an easy way comparable to `simple-oauth2`.

Comment: Have you looked into asp identity? Also there are few libs that handle oauth2. Check this one out https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html

Comment: Do you want get access token with C# or you want read token stored in db?

Comment: In C# I want to read the current token to use it. If it is expired I want to use the refresh token to get a new one to use going forward.